# flex datagrid do not append rows

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4.5

how can i stop rows of data being appended to my data grid? i toggle between states. each time i go back to the update_dg_form state additional networkInfo rows are added to the datagrid.

```
private function update_dg(event:MouseEvent):void
{           
    var ntf:Vector.<NetworkInterface> = NetworkInfo.networkInfo.findInterfaces();
    for each (var interfaceObj:NetworkInterface in ntf)
    {
        networkInfo.addItem({"dg_display_name" : interfaceObj.displayName, "dg_mac_address" : interfaceObj.hardwareAddress});
    }
        currentState = 'update_dg_form';                    
}

<mx:DataGrid id="network_adapter" includeIn="update_dg_form" x="55" y="280" width="516" height="111" dataProvider="{networkInfo}" selectedIndex="0">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="dg_display_name" headerText="Network Adapter"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="dg_mac_address" headerText="MAC Address"/>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Comment: I guess the appending happens because of the for each loop ?

Comment: good guess. the thing is all examples i've seen use for each loops.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all elements from networkInfo before insertion new info using `networkInfo.removeAll();`

```
private function update_dg(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var ntf:Vector.<NetworkInterface> = NetworkInfo.networkInfo.findInterfaces();
    networkInfo.removeAll();
    for each (var interfaceObj:NetworkInterface in ntf) {
        networkInfo.addItem({"dg_display_name":interfaceObj.displayName, "dg_mac_address":interfaceObj.hardwareAddress});
    }
    currentState = 'update_dg_form';
}

<mx:DataGrid id="network_adapter" includeIn="update_dg_form" x="55" y="280" width="516" height="111" dataProvider="{networkInfo}" selectedIndex="0">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="dg_display_name" headerText="Network Adapter"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="dg_mac_address" headerText="MAC Address"/>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Comment: i tried that. rows don't append, but the selectedIndex="0" no longer works. the first row in datagrid isn't highlighted.